# Using maven the resources folder is not getting generated at the same level where class files are getting generated

Tags: maven

I am having my directory structure as

```
src/
- main/
  - java/
    - com/
      - resources/  // Folder where I have kept my properties file
      - class1.java
      - class2.java
```

When I am trying to build the JAR using maven the resources folder is getting skipped and I am having only this structure left

```
src/
- main/
  - java/
    - com/
      - class1.class
      - class2.class
```

I know that maven uses a conventional dir. structure for the resources as `src/main/resources`. But I want my resources folder to be at the same level where my class files are getting generated.

Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want a different way than Maven says? Which is the advantage of your way?

Comment: Why do your property files end in `.java`? It's not a property file if it is compiled. Property files should be processed at runtime so thay are changeable after compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The key is what you said - you want your resources to be at the same level where the class files are being *generated*.  That doesn't mean they have to *start* in the same folder.  They must simply have the same package structure.  You may do this following the normal Maven file layout conventions as follows.

```
- src
  - main
  | - java
  |   - com
  |     - mycompany
  |       - Class1.java
  |       - Class2.java
  | - resources  
  |   - com
  |     - mycompany
  |       - someResources.properties
  |       - anotherResource.jpg
```

Note that the directory/package structure under `/src/main/java` and `/src/main/resources` is the same.  When the `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-resources-plugin` have finished running, the result will be

```
- target
  - classes
    - com
      - mycompany
        - Class1.class
        - Class2.class
        - someResources.properties
        - anotherResource.jpg
```

which is what you want.